# Redshift ERROR: relation "Temp table" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

under AWS Redshift

I created a temp table with

```
select all 
*
into temp table #cleaned_fact
from fact_table
limit 100
```

get

> Executed successfully
>
> Updated 0 rows in 0.716 seconds.

and try to check the data in temp table with

```
select *
from #cleaned_fact
```

get error

> ERROR: relation "#cleaned_fact" does not exist

=======================================================
update 1.

be careful

> The temp table exists only for duration of your session using which
>   you have created the table.

```
    create temp table IF NOT EXISTS #cleaned_fact
(
col1 INT NOT NULL encode delta,
col2 INT NOT NULL encode mostly16,
col3 INT NOT NULL encode runlength,
col4 BIGINT NOT NULL encode mostly32,
);
insert into #cleaned_fact
select *
from fact_channel_posting
limit 100
```

returns

> Executed successfully
>
> Updated 100 rows in 3.101 seconds.

but in another session select * from #cleaned_fact still returns the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way to create temp table

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
[(create_definition,...)]
[table_options]
select_statement



CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable
(id int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable SELECT id FROM table WHERE xyz;
```

Comment: thx for the response. tried still the same error by selecting from temp table

Answer (score 1):

The strategy in update 1 succeeded. The problem was:

> The temp table exists only for duration of your session using which
>   you have created the table.